# Why is one variable working on one page and not on the other?

Tags: php, apache, session, phpmyadmin

im trying to make a log in system but one page of mine is working and not the other, please help!

Here is the first page which it working

```
<?php
/* Displays user information and some useful messages */
session_start();

// Check if user is logged in using the session variable
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {
$_SESSION['message'] = "You must log in before viewing your profile page!";
header("location: error.php");    
}  
else {
// Makes it easier to read
$first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
$last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$active = $_SESSION['active'];
}
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>   
  <html >  
  <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Welcome <?= $first_name.' '.$last_name ?></title>
  <?php include 'css/css.html'; ?>
   </head>
  <body>
<div class="form">

      <h1>Welcome</h1>

      <p>
      <?php 

      // Display message about account verification link only once
      if ( isset($_SESSION['message']) )
      {
          echo $_SESSION['message'];

          // Don't annoy the user with more messages upon page refresh
          unset( $_SESSION['message'] );
      }

      ?>
      </p>

      <?php

      // Keep reminding the user this account is not active, until they 
activate
      if ( !$active ){
          echo
          '<div class="info">
          Account is unverified, please confirm your email by clicking
          on the email link!
          </div>';
      }

      ?>

      <h2><?php echo $first_name.' '.$last_name; ?></h2>
      <p><?= $email ?></p>

      <a href="logout.php"><button class="button button-block" 
 name="logout"/>Log Out</button></a>

</div>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this page, where it says :

```
  <title>Welcome <?= $first_name.' '.$last_name ?></title>
```

It is working and saying welcome and the user's name.

But in this page:

```
<?php
session_start();
// any HTML input *must* be HTML-escaped to prevent the user from injecting 
malicious JavaScript code
function html_escape($raw_input, $encoding)
{
return htmlspecialchars($raw_input, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, $encoding);
}

/* Displays user information and some useful messages */

if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1) {
$first_name = 'Guest, Please Login or Sign Up to Play!';
$last_name = '';
}
else {
// Makes it easier to read
$first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
$last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
}
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CashBallz</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><!
[endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><!
[endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><!
[endif]-->
</head>
<body class="landing">
    <div id="page-wrapper">

        <!-- Header -->
            <header id="header">
                <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.php">CashBallz</a></h1>
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Play</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="left-sidebar.php">Server 1</a>
</li>
                                <li><a href="right-sidebar.php">Server 2</a>
 </li>
                                <li><a href="no-sidebar.php">Server 3</a>
</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="elements.php">Paypal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="loginsystem/loginpage.php" 
class="button special">Sign Up/Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <br>
                <p style="float:right; font-size: 30px" > 
                    Welcome <?php= $first_name.' '.$last_name ?>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </p>
            </header>

        <!-- Banner -->
            <section id="banner">
                <div class="content">
                    <header>
                        <h2>CashBallz</h2>
                        <p>The best way to make money by having fun.</p>
                    </header>
                    <span class="image"><img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" 
/></span>
                </div>
                <a href="#one" class="goto-next scrolly">Next</a>
            </section>

        <!-- Explain -->
            <section id="one" class="spotlight style1 bottom">
                <span class="image fit main"><img src="images/pic02.jpg" 
alt="" /></span>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="4u 12u$(medium)">
                                <header>
                                    <h2>The Game</h2>
                                    <p>CashBallz was made by two students to 
help people gain easy money by having fun!</p>
                                </header>
                            </div>
                            <div class="4u 12u$(medium)">
                                <p>We had trouble finding ways to make money 
because we werent old enough to get a job. So we decided to create a fun way 
to 
make money for ourselves and other people!</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="4u$ 12u$(medium)">
                                <p>We hope you enjoy our game as much as we 
did creating it.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#two" class="goto-next scrolly">Next</a>
            </section>

        <!-- How to start playing -->
            <section id="two" class="spotlight style2 right">
                <span class="image fit main"><img src="images/pic03.jpg" 
alt="" /></span>
                <div class="content">
                    <header>
                        <h2>How to start playing!</h2>
                        <p>First, press sign up. You will be directed to a 
page where you have to create an account with your paypal.</p>
                    </header>
                    <p>Log in with your paypal with our secure servers. 
Then, press any server with the most people, and start playing!</p>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><a href="loginsystem/loginpage.php" 
class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <a href="#three" class="goto-next scrolly">Next</a>
            </section>

        <!-- How to play the game -->
            <section id="three" class="spotlight style3 left">
                <span class="image fit main bottom"><img 
src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="" /></span>
                <div class="content">
                    <header>
                        <h2>How to play the game / controls</h2>
                        <p>Use WASD or the arrow keys to move around.<p>
                        <p>Press space to split, and press shift to let out 
a one-cent blob.<p>
                    </header>
                    <p>This game is similiar to Agar.io, eat another player 
to gain their mass and price. Eat the small blobs to gain mass, but no 
money.
</p>
                    <p>Press "C" to cash out, it will take 10 seconds of non 
movement to leave the game with all your money.<p>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><a href="#" class="button">Control Page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <a href="#four" class="goto-next scrolly">Next</a>
            </section>

        <!-- Strategies -->
            <section id="four" class="wrapper style1 special fade-up">
                <div class="container">
                    <header class="major">
                        <h2>Strategies to win!</h2>
                        <p>There are many ways to beat other players and 
gain money faster!</p>
                    </header>
                    <div class="box alt">
                        <div class="row uniform">
                            <section class="4u 6u(medium) 12u$(xsmall)">
                                <span class="icon alt major fa-area-chart">
</span>
                                <h3>Split!</h3>
                                <p>Split to catch other blobs that are less 
than 1/2 your size!</p>
                            </section>
                            <section class="4u 6u$(medium) 12u$(xsmall)">
                                <span class="icon alt major fa-comment">
</span>
                                <h3>Eleifend lorem ornare</h3>
                                <p>Feugiat accumsan lorem eu ac lorem amet 
accumsan donec. Blandit orci porttitor.</p>
                            </section>
                            <section class="4u$ 6u(medium) 12u$(xsmall)">
                                <span class="icon alt major fa-flask">
</span>
                                <h3>Cubilia cep lobortis</h3>
                                <p>Feugiat accumsan lorem eu ac lorem amet 
accumsan donec. Blandit orci porttitor.</p>
                            </section>
                            <section class="4u 6u$(medium) 12u$(xsmall)">
                                <span class="icon alt major fa-paper-plane">
</span>
                                <h3>Non semper interdum</h3>
                                <p>Feugiat accumsan lorem eu ac lorem amet 
accumsan donec. Blandit orci porttitor.</p>
                            </section>
                            <section class="4u 6u(medium) 12u$(xsmall)">
                                <span class="icon alt major fa-file"></span>
                                <h3>Odio laoreet accumsan</h3>
                                <p>Feugiat accumsan lorem eu ac lorem amet 
accumsan donec. Blandit orci porttitor.</p>
                            </section>
                            <section class="4u$ 6u$(medium) 12u$(xsmall)">
                                <span class="icon alt major fa-lock"></span>
                                <h3>Massa arcu accumsan</h3>
                                <p>Feugiat accumsan lorem eu ac lorem amet 
accumsan donec. Blandit orci porttitor.</p>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <footer class="major">
                        <ul class="actions">
                            <li><a href="#" class="button">Magna sed 
feugiat</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </section>

        <!-- How you're making money -->
            <section id="five" class="wrapper style2 special fade">
                <div class="container">
                    <header>
                        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                        <p>Start playing today!</p>
                    </header>
                    <form method="post" action="#" class="container 50%">
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="8u 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="email" 
name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" /></div>
                            <div class="4u$ 12u$(xsmall)"><input 
type="submit" value="Get Started" class="fit special" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>

        <!-- Footer -->
            <footer id="footer">
                <ul class="icons">
                    <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-twitter"><span 
class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-facebook"><span 
class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-instagram"><span 
class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-envelope"><span 
class="label">Email</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="copyright">
                    <li>&copy; Untitled. All rights reserved.</li>
<li>Creator: <a href="http://html5up.net">CashBallz.Co</a></li>
                </ul>
            </footer>

    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js">
</script><![endif]-->
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

It does not say the user name or last name, or even the guest message, when it says this:

```
Welcome <?php= $first_name.' '.$last_name ?>
```

I set the variable both times the same, and i dont understand what's wrong
I don't know if this is helpful, but these two pages are in different folders and all of the session and database php files is in the folder of the first page, but i dont know if that matters.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need that line to say:

```
Welcome <?php echo $first_name.' '.$last_name ?>
```

I'm not sure about the <?= ?> notation you're using, but I imagine that has something to do with it. Your second one is <?php= instead of <?= which is probably not doing what you expect. I think those are called [php short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) if you're interested in reading more about them.

Comment: alright it worked but i'm getting an error that says undefined index: logged_in on line 11

Comment: You should always check if your indexes exist: if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']) { // handle logged in } else { // redirect to login page }

Comment: no problem, thanks for your help

Comment: Now its saying "Undefined variable: last_name" and first name

Comment: @Patrick instead of using if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1), use if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))

Answer (score 0):

You either use `<?=$var?>` or `<?php echo $var;?>`

So change the problem line to this

```
<p style="float:right; font-size: 30px" > 
    Welcome <?= $first_name.' '.$last_name?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
</p>
```

OR

```
<p style="float:right; font-size: 30px" > 
    Welcome <?php echo $first_name .' '. $last_name;?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
</p>
```